# error while select 1 combobox as dependent combobox using ajax and vbscript

Tags: ajax, vbscript, combobox, asp-classic

i m using 2 dependent combobox in my page. when i select value from 1st combobox (by default it is "select state"), in 2nd combobox value is displaying correct and working fine but when i select again "select state" option(with no value) in 1st combobox then its showing alert saying "there was a problem while using XMLHTTP. internal server error" instead of showing "select city" option(with no value) in 2nd combobox. please help me out to solve this issue.

here is my ajax script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getXMLHTTP() { 
var xmlhttp=false;  
try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {       
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
}

    return xmlhttp;
}

function getcity(stateId) {     

    var strURL="findcity.asp?state="+stateId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                      document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                        
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }       
}

</script>
```

here is my code
for populate state

```
<select name="state_name" onChange="getcity(this.value)">
```

i have added value="0" in Select State

```
<option value="0">Select State</option> ' edited
<%while not Objrs_state.eof%>
<option value="<%=Objrs_state("ASId")%>"><%=Objrs_state("ASName")%></option>
<%Objrs_state.movenext
wend
Objrs_state.close
set Objrs_state = nothing
set objCmd_state = nothing%>
    </select>
```

for populate city

```
<span id="citydiv"><select name="city" >
<option>Select City</option>
    </select></span>
```

here is findcity.asp code

```
<select name="city">
<% Do While Not Objrs_city.EOF %>
<option value="<%= objrs_city("ACId")%>"><%= Objrs_city("ACName")%></option>
<%
Objrs_city.MoveNext
Loop
%>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Probably, you have a query in the findcity.asp page where you are appending the state id to the query in that page.

Try changing the state dropdown html:

```
<select name="state_name" onChange="getcity(this.value)">
<option >Select State</option>
....
```

To:

```
<select name="state_name" onChange="getcity(this.value)">
<option value="0">Select State</option>
```

That is, give a value of `0` to the first option

w.r.t to your comment, to show `select city` add an initial option to the dropdown in findcity.asp

```
<select name="city">
<option value="0">select city</option>
<% Do While Not Objrs_city.EOF %>
....
```

Comment: i have edited line "<option >Select State</option>" to "<option value="0">Select State</option>". Now there is no error alert and works fine but when i select "Select State" option second time how i did earlier, 2nd combobox showing blank and not showing option "Select City". please help me

Comment: yes it is working fine now. thanks a lot to you and this site.